# Sending email using TIdSMTP and TIdMessage

Tags: delphi, smtp, indy, dbgrid, tdbgrid

I'm using an action from my `ActionManager` to send an email to a client in my `DBGrid`.

I select the `row` with the client details in my `DBGrid`, right click, a `Popupactionbar` comes up, I click the send mail action and the mail should be sending.

This is the code for the mail send action:

```
procedure TForm2.actSendEmailExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
IdSMTP1.Host := 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com';
IdSMTP1.Port := 465;

//setup mail message
IdMessage1.From.Address := 'my email address is here';
IdMessage1.Recipients.EMailAddresses := DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet['email'];
IdMessage1.Subject   := 'test subject';
IdMessage1.Body.Text := 'test email body' + DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet['details'];

//send mail try
IdSMTP1.Connect ;
IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1) ;
IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
end;
```

I'm using `TIdSMTP` and `TIdMessage` (Indy components).
I've also set the hostname, port, username and password in the `TIdSMTP` Properties using Object Inspector, all details are as yahoo provided them on their website (hostname, port, my email for login and my email password)

In the row I select in `DBGrid` there is a field named email which contains the mail address of the client, hence that is where the email should go.
Also, I'm adding some information contained in a field named details, which should go in the body section of the email (see above code)

Once I start my software up, select the row in `DBGrid` and hit send on the action button, the software freezes (not responding) for somewhere around 20-40 seconds than it returns an error saying: Connection closed gracefully.

I'm using yahoo smtp just to test things out, I would eventually be using the smtp from my hosting provider that hosts my website (and where the db is located also)

Indy version 10.6.2.5311
Using Delphi 10 Seattle

Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this relate to missing SSL libraries?  I just note that you're using port 465; isn't that for SSL connections?

I've never worked with the TIdSMTP component, but I've seen a similar situation occur with the TIdHTTP component (the connection times out without any obvious indication as to why) when attempting to use use an SSL connection unless the appropriate DLLs have been made available.  They aren't an integral part of Indy (I imagine it's a legal issue regarding the use of encryption in some countries) but they are freely available elsewhere.

Edit:  *The component also has a "UseTLS" property which may not have been set.*

Comment: Dunno, I'm using that port because thats what Yahoo says to use for that hostname. Could very well be the case, any thought on where to get those libraries and where do I need to put them?

Comment: Indy's own website links to one set you can download:  http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/ssl.en.aspx.

They'll work from the directory with the executable.  Either that or choose a location and add it to your default paths.

Comment: Any idea which one from that huge list to use? I got the last on the list and that didn't do it. My Indy version is 10.6.2.5311 - I'm using Delphi 10 Seattle, tried with 1.0.2h and 1.0.2j. Also, I did notice the UseTLS option, it's currently set by default to utNoTLSSupport. If I try any of the other options (explicit, implicit or require) it immediately gives an error in the IDE saying: SSL IOHandler is required for this setting.

Comment: The default IOHandler doesn't support SSL, so it's looking for a component such as a TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.  You'll need to add one and set the IOHandler property of the TIdSMTP component to use it.

Comment: As to the version of OpenSSL to use: that depends on your target platform.

A 32-bit Windows target requires the "i386" version of the DLLs, a 64-bit Windows target requires the "x64" version.

I'd take the most up-to-date ones on that list, which at the moment seems to be _v1.0.2j_.

Comment: Hello Owen, sorry for the late reply. Indeed, that seemed to be the problem, at least the IOHandler, added the component and set it in TIdSMTP and it works like charm - no idea if the 2 drivers helped or not but I've also included those. Thanks for the help, I've accepted your answer. If you like, edit it and add these further details from the last 2 comments os more people can see them should they ever come across this. Cheers mate, have a good one.